# ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cannot be converted into JSONArray properly for API9

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I'm having a problem about storing my `ArrayList` into my shared preferences. What I decided to to is to convert the `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` into `JSONArray` so that I can parse the JSON next time I need it since I can't store the ArrayList> as string and bring it back on its original form.

Now what happens is that the `ArrayList` is converted successfully into JSON format for my device running in API 19 but strange thing is that it doesn't convert properly for my emulator device running in API 9. When I check the reason, it is because the converted string is not properly formatted which results into an error. By *not properly formatted*, I mean that instead of having a format of `[{"key":"value"}]` it is being converted into `[{key:value}]` wherein the double quotes are removed which is required for JSON causing this error message:

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character
```

Here's the code:

```
private void storeStatusInSharedPreference(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items){
    SharedPreferences my_prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);

    JSONArray result = new JSONArray(items);
    my_prefs.edit().putString("test", result.toString()).apply();

}
```

I'm not sure if same thing will happen for other devices/versions since I only test on those two which is why I didn't apply any API version checking to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to store Array list in your sharedprefrences,

Sharedpreferences Allow to store String so use like this may to help you

```
private void storeStatusInSharedPreference(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items){
    SharedPreferences my_prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);

    //JSONArray result = new JSONArray(items);
    my_prefs.edit().putString("test", items.toString()).commit();
}
```

This will be Work fine.